# Check if a string contains at least two of the strings in a list

Tags: python

I want to know if there are at least 2 words from a list in a string. Some words are duplicate in the list. I would like to find two ***different*** words in the string from the list.

I tried this:

```
keywords = ["word1", "word1", "word1", "word2", "word3"]
r = "word4 word2 word1 word5"

for keyword in keywords:
    if keyword in r:
        for keyword2 in keywords:
            if keyword2 in r:
                if keyword2 != keyword:
                    status="ok"
                    print("here at least 2 words matching")
                    break
```

Comment: can you show the first few lines of the csv

Comment: If string is "word1 word0 word1". Is that a match if there are two "word1" in the csv list too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put the words from csv in a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set). Then you can use ’set.intersection()` to find all the words common to the string.

```py
keyword_set = set(keywords)
common = keyword_set.intersection(r.split())
if len(common) >= 2:
    print('Found:', common)
```

The approach suggested by Tomerikoo that breaks as soon as two items are found is faster and can be altered to stop if two of the same word are found too. But it only prints the first two matches even if there are more. Here's a shortened version:

```py
# To find only unique words, use `words_found = set()`
words_found = []
for word in set(keywords):
    if word in r:
        # If words_found is a set, use `words_found.add(word)`
        words_found.append(word)
        if len(words_found) >= 2:
            print("Found:", words_found)
            break
```

Answer (score 2):

First convert to a `set` to remove the duplicates. Then create an iterator on that set and check that you can match the wanted amount of words:

```py
keywords = iter(set(keywords))
num_of_words_to_find = 2
words_found = []

for _ in range(num_of_words_to_find-1):
    for word in keywords:
        if word in r:
            words_found.append(word)
            break

for word in keywords:
    if word in r:
        words_found.append(word)
        print(f"Found {num_of_words_to_find} words:", ', '.join(words_found))
        break
else:
    print(f"No {num_of_words_to_find} different words in string")
```

Comment: Hello. Why is there two "if word in keywords" lines ?

Comment: You wanted to check for two words... The first loop stops when the first word is found. Then the second loop makes sure that another word is found

Comment: sorry, I didn't read the "set" for the duplicate

Comment: If I want to print the two words found?

Comment: Just save them to a list or print them under the `if word in r:`...

Comment: @Mathieu I really appreciate you accepting my answer and this might be unorthodox, but I really think that [the solution by Jolbas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66337526/6045800) is the right one for this question and should be accepted. It is much more scalable, i.e. if now now you want to check for at least 3 strings, it change a change of one number. In my code you will need to add a whole new loop

Comment: Maybe just use one loop and report and break if `len(words_found) >= 2`

Comment: @Jolbas lol you're right. I passed a few iterations of this code with myself that I lost sight of the simple things... Still your answer is the one to go with ;)

Answer (score 0):

Load the csv word list in a string list, remove duplicates, and then for every word

```
counter = 0
for keyword in wordslist:
    if keyword in r:
        print(keyword + " in string")
        counter = counter + 1

if counter >= 2:
    print("at least two matching words are in the string")
```

Comment: You could put a counter of the number of times a word comes up in the string

Comment: That's a good one also. But how do you print all found keywords?

Comment: My function iterates through all the keywords and prints them if they found it, you can put the found words in a list and print them if you want. I fixed my function a little bit and brought the second if statement outside the for loop